# moving to catkin from rosmake

Tags: catkin, ros-fuerte, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bunch of packages that are using the old rosmake build system and they no longer compile, so I'd like to move to catkin--is there a howto I missed somewhere? [This](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/catkin/html/index.html) works as a reference, but it's not very straight forward...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34255/moving-to-catkin-from-rosmake/) by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1607 on 2012-05-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-17**:
Are they broken because of catkin, or just ordinary bit-rot?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-17**:
Relevant Groovy SIG: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Planning/Buildsystem

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2012-05-18**:
@joq: they compile/run in electric just fine. Should fuerte compile legacy rosbuild packages, because on my two fuerte systems that seems not to be the case. Should I file bugs?

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-18**:
With rosmake, it should compile legacy packages, but many packages cleaned up their export flags or were converted to rosdeps, so you may have to update your manifest.xml and CMakeLists accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some things that were deprecated in Electric were removed in Fuerte. You probably ran into something like that.

Check the [Fuerte migration guide](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Migration) for details.

If your problems are not mentioned there, bug reports would be worthwhile.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1